# Sentiment analysis using spark and Stanford NLP API

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

When I wanted to do a sentiment analysis project I searched alot online, and atlast I landed on this website, which explained the code but what it did not explain is how to use spark with respect to the code, I mean where to add the code. 
Website :http://stdatalabs.blogspot.in/2017/09/twitter-sentiment-analysis-using-spark.html?m=1

It will be of great help, if anyone can explain me completely, as Iam a begginer and this my first project on big data.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the bottom there is a link to the github (https://github.com/stdatalabs/sparkNLP-elasticsearch) you should check that out (literally)

The main class is 
`com.stdatalabs.SparkES.TwitterSentimentAnalysis` according to the pom.xml

So running `mvn package` will yield you an executable .jar (user `java -jar`)

Running the jar will prompt you for some twitter config (keys, etc) and saves to a local es cluster using hardcoded index (& mapping) `twitter_020717/tweet`

You can now alter the code anyway you want, build, run, and check the results.